# android - for loop drawing circles not working?

Tags: android, draw

I am trying to draw multiple circles from an array and it is throwing a "force close" when I try to run the code. Any ideas here?

```
package com.adam.PlaySound;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ButtonPress extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int numPlayers = 3;
    boolean toggle = true;
    LinearLayout parent;
    Button button;
    TextView text;
    TextView text2;
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer[] = new MediaPlayer[numPlayers];
    //this array is a placeholder for the loops in a cluster
    //essentially this array will be populated through a database
    //based on which cluster someone is within
    //and the region arrays will be populated by the same database
    String soundFiles[] = {"drums_1.mp3", "lead.mp3", "strings.mp3"};
    public LoopRegion region[] = new LoopRegion[numPlayers];
    float regionX[] = {20, 80, 150};
    float regionY[] = {20, 200, 350};
    int regionR[] = {50, 80, 100};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //setContentView(R.id.view1);

        parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        parent.setOnTouchListener(Motion);
        button.setOnClickListener(on_off);


        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
            String path = "http://soundclusters.adamlaskowitz.com/uploads/" + soundFiles[i];
            mediaPlayer[i] = new  MediaPlayer();
            //mediaPlayer[i] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonPress.this, R.raw.drums_2);
            mediaPlayer[i] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonPress.this, Uri.parse(path));
            mediaPlayer[i].setLooping(true);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
            region[i] = new LoopRegion(this,regionX[i],regionY[i],regionR[i]);
            parent.addView(region[i]);
        }

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); 


    }
```

This is the LoopRegion class.

```
package com.adam.PlaySound;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;


/*This class will create a circle region for
 *each loop within a cluster */
public class LoopRegion extends View {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private int r;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public LoopRegion(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
    super(context);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
}

public void setCoordinate(float mx, float my){
    this.x = mx;
    this.y = my;
    //this.r = 300;
    }
}
```

And this is the XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    >
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Not Playing"
    />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Location" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
<Button android:text="Sound On/Off" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
<!-- <View android:id="@+id/view1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </View>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check logcat for the exception. It should point to the line that's causing the problem.

Comment: So I realized that I was never defining how many LoopRegion classes to create (this is my circle draw class). I fixed that and it runs without errors now. Only problem is that it is only drawing 1 circle, not each circle for the amount of items I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your LoopRegion views have layout parameters set to FILL_PARENT and the first one pushes the others off the screen. It would help to see the code for how a LoopRegion is created, and perhaps the XML for the parent LinearLayout.

Comment: I have added the following: LoopRegion class, and main XML as an edit on the original post due to time restrictions on answering posts for a new user.

Comment: Also, the ButtonPress class code that I provided is not complete, but everything that pertains to the drawing of circles is included... Thanks

Comment: Since each circle is a separate view, they are being stacked one on top of the other by the LinearLayout. Since you specify no layout params, they get layout_width=MATCH_PARENT and layout_height=WRAP_CONTENT. You also don't have (or haven't posted) code for onMeasure. (I suspect you have some, otherwise I think the view would be zero height.) Assuming your onMeasure tries to keep the view square, the first is probably pushing the lower views off the screen. I'd suggest using hierarchyviewer to check where your views are actually going.

Comment: Also, by using views this way, you aren't going to get any overlapping circles. Perhaps that's the way you want it. But if not, consider creating a single custom view instance that draws all your circles, rather than a separate view for each circle.

Comment: Ted, thank you so much for response. I have a question though (also I should mention I am fairly new to programming in Android), how is it that my circles are being drawn on separate views? Aren't I telling each circle to be drawn on the LinearLayout?

Comment: I actually just created an "AbsoluteLayout" within the LinearLayout and added the circles to that view instead of the LinearLayout view, this seems to work perfectly...
'code'for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
         region[i] = new LoopRegion(this,regionX[i],regionY[i],regionR[i], true);
         border[i] = new LoopRegion(this,regionX[i],regionY[i],regionR[i], false);
         circles.addView(region[i]);
         circles.addView(border[i]);
        }'code'